# How to collect `ip`, `pageViewId` with the Retail API's Google tag manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are collecting the Retail API through Google tag manager. In the documentation, it says that if you collect via google tag manager, the fields are automatically collected.

https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.userEvents#resource:-userevent

[Retail API Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRJyU.png)

Is there any way to check if they are being collected?